# Split binary file based on string

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, split

I have 170 1GB binary files, where I would like to split them everytime I find specific ASCII strings. Some of these strings also have newlines.

`csplit` seams like the perfect tool for this task, but it seams it doesn't work on binary files.

**Question**

If I convert the search strings to hex/binary, does that make the problem easier to solve, so it is binary search in binary data?

If not, how do I split binary files based in ASCII strings where some of them have newlines?

Comment: Do you want python, perl or bash code?

Comment: I am open to all of them =) The one that can solve the problem easiest =)

Comment: In what way does `csplit` not work?

Comment: There isn't anything special about *binary* files other than that they often contain bytes that wouldn't appear in a text file, and they don't look nice when you print them. They're still a sequence of octets that must be comprehended, and most decent languages let you do just that.

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81276/splitting-a-large-binary-file-into-sections-determined-by-context-patterns

Comment: `csplit` works on a line basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything special about binary files other than that they often contain data that wouldn't appear in a text file, and they don't look nice when you print them. They're still a sequence of octets that must be comprehended, and most decent languages let you do just that.

An example may help.

You don't describe the string that you want to use as a separator, and you don't say what you want to do with each chunk once it has been read, so here is a Perl program that reads the 1GB original file in chunks that end with `specific ASCII string` and writes them out one at a time to a new file. So it rather clumsily copies the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<:raw', '1GBfile' or die $!;
local $/ = 'specific ASCII string';

open my $out_fh, '>:raw', 'new1GBfile' or die $!;
select $out_fh;

print while <$fh>;

close $out_fh or die $!;
```

Depending on what you're doing with the data from the file, you may find [`File::Map`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Map) useful

Answer (score 1):

You could change the input record separator `$/` to be the specific search string you want to split on (by default, it is a newline). Then as you read the input file, print each record to a new unique file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# change the input record separator to whatever string you want
$/ = "SOME STRING";

my $file_num = 0;
while (my $data = <>) {
  chomp $data; # remove input record separator
  my $file = "file." . ++$file_num;
  open my $fh, '>', $file or die "can't open file: $file: $!\n";
  print $fh $data;
  close $fh;
}
```

Comment: This won't work on Windows because the Perl IO layer `:crlf` has removed carriage returns characters `"\x0D"` before your program sees the data. It also won't work on old-style Mac boxes, but that's less likely.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin. That's good to know. In this case, the OP is looking for a solution for Linux, but it is better to strive for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: That's why it's a *comment* :)  What many people don't get is that Stack Overflow isn't a forum, where one individual's problem can be discussed to find them a solution, but more of a Wikipedia of solutions to programming problems. The OP should be very low on your list of people to satisfy because, if it is a good question, there will be another thousand that follow them searching for a solution to a similar problem. If those others come across your solution that *looks* like it should do what they want then you have let them down.

Comment: It is trivial to turn off the `:crlf` layer on Windows. or to turn it on for other platforms.

Comment: @mob: Yes, it is trivial to do. But knowing that is necessary is more of a game of chance